# I am trying to follow a tutorial and the tutorial code works but my code doesn't

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner who is trying JS for the first time, and I have encountered a problem. First the tutorial suggested me a challenge to go through and as i wrote the code it had a lot of bugs. Then i saw the solution, wrote the code as the solution and surprisingly the tutorial's code was working but my one doesn't. I wrote the code same as the solution but it doesn't seem to be working. please help!!!!!!!!!
here is the JS code

```
    var numberOfDrumButtons= document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons.length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", handleclick)
}



function handleclick(){
  alert( "i got clicked" )
}
```

Comment: Just remove `.length` from the loop i mean this part `numberOfDrumButtons.length` because you already get the length in `numberOfDrumButtons` variable

Comment: omg it works thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberOfDrumButtons= document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons.length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", handleclick)
}

function handleclick(){
  alert( "i got clicked" )
}
```

If you look at the first line of code you are already getting length of the output. Just remove `.length` in the first line because you getting the length of numberOfDrumButtons variable in the second line

Comment: it works man thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.length` from top and your code works fine check this example:

OR
you can remove numberOfDrumButtons`.length` either one of these works

```js
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons.length; i++) {
  numberOfDrumButtons[i].addEventListener("click", handleclick)
}



function handleclick() {
  alert("i got clicked")
}
```

```html
<button class='drum'>button1</button>
<button class='drum'>button2</button>
<button class='drum'>button3</button>
<button class='drum'>button4</button>
<button class='drum'>button5</button>
<button class='drum'>button6</button>
<button class='drum'>button7</button>
```